# What can I do to make this search script to work for each of my table columns?

Tags: javascript

I am using [a bit of code from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) because its exactly what I'm looking for, but I need to make it work for multiple table columns. I know what the problem is, the `input = document.getElementById("search");` line will find the first ID and use it. I need a way for it to be unique without making a script for every column. Otherwise it works and its scalable with my tables. Here is the code I'm using:

HTML

```
<tr>
        <th><input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="searchFunction(0)"></th>
        <th><input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="searchFunction(1)"></th>
        <th><input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="searchFunction(2)"></th>
        <th><input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="searchFunction(3)"></th>
</tr>
```

JS

```
function searchFunction(n) {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("search");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("table");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
                if (td) {
                        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                                tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Searching other answers led me to try things like `input = n.querySelector('.search')`, use searchFunction(this), and change all of the HTML IDs to classes, but I still get

> TypeError: input is null

I have no idea if I am on the right track or not

Comment: Well, you could give them IDs that match your `n`, like `search0`, `search1`, etc., then use `document.getElementById("search" + n)`...

Comment: I had thought about this, but I didnt know how to actually write it. That does work

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having unique id attributes on your page. You can change the `id`s to `class`es and use `document.querySelectorAll('.search')` to get the list of inputs.

Comment: Oops. Must have mis-typed

Answer (score 0):

DOM (Document Object Model) doesn't work correctly if some `id`s of elements are the same.
They must be unique no matter what.

Change `id`s of your input fields for them to be unique.